# How to find information in wikipedia dumps

Tags: dump, wikipedia

I will apologize as I am quite a new to SQL.

I wanted to avoid crawling wikipedia, so I started looking for other way of doing it.
DBPedia seemed like a possible solution but after an hour of looking where to start I turned back to wikipedia dumps.

The question there I have is how do I find what I want in the dumps ? Which dumps do I need to  find a particular info ? There are so meny dumps there and they contribute to different parts of structure. Do I need to downlaod all of them to get a hundred megabytes worth of data ?

I have looked into the Mediawiki database structure, but that did not help much.

Has anyone done something like that before ? I am particularly interested in the tables wiki does about athletes and such. Is there some way to track which info or link related information in which particular wiki dump ?

EDIT: I am trying to get a list of athletes of all sports, with names, ages, sport, medals ... etc ...

Comment: You're not telling us what you want to do, but you expect we will know which dumps you will need?

Comment: Well I am not really asking for a specific dumps, but for the way to navigate through them. I edited the post for the details of what I am looking for specifically.

Comment: it looked more complicated then just restoring dumps and getting stuff from the "primary" source,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia (or its dumps) doesn't really contain the structured information you're looking for. If you want to find out what medals some athlete won, you could try parsing that athlete's article to find the template used for medals. But doing this will be most likely difficult, because the templates are often not standardized and change over time.

I think DBPedia would be much better for your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Having the same question ... at this exact moment in my life. I spend some time on it - and the answer is -> There is no page that gives you a preview of the data dumps so that you can se a small part of them before you download the whole gigantic mammoth database set - that by the way is a big problem to parse in any normal text application. If you have acces to a terminal use "cat" command to look what's inside - by far the fastest way.

I knew what i wanted to find - a dump containing pageId and Titles - no info on which dump contained that. So i had to search search search -> nothing .. then i just had to download like 10-15 dumps of different kinds to open them and see if i could use it.

Turns out the dump: enwiki-latest-page.sql.gz  contained all pageIds and titles of eng. wikipedia. Which just in general is a useful dump since you from pageId can request all the text and content of any wikipage and you can use the title to know what this pageId is an Id for.